# CKEditor with MVC: Event handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, jquery-events

I have the following code, which generates my default CKEditor on my form:

```
$('#Content').ckeditor({
    filebrowserUploadUrl: '/ControlPanel/Reviews/UploadReviewImage/'
});
```

As you can see, my implementation is quite simple - most settings are controlled in config.js and are global to my site, except the uploader handlers.

Been looking for a few days, but can't find anything concise. I need to be able to detect when CKEditor is clicked, and make the window larger (though not full screen). I also want to display some help text when CKEditor is clicked... but I can't figure out how to handle dom events, or apply JQuery events to it? I've tried a few different things, the following  being my latest attempt:

```
$("#Content").ckeditorGet().click(window.showDescription);
```

But I get a TypeError:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'click'

Which is understandable, as CKEditor has its own event system.

The CKEditor documentation seems very unintuitive - and the examples aren't really much help.

---

**UPDATE**

I managed to get this working on my own, though because of thw way I've written my window.ShowDescription function, I needed to pass a JQuery event in to it. Here's the code for anyone interested :)

```
$("#Content").ckeditorGet().on("instanceReady", function () {
        this.on("focus", function () {
            this.resize(638);
            // Mimic JQuery event for textarea
            var originalEditor = $(this.container.$).parents(".input").find("textarea");
            originalEditor.trigger(jQuery.Event("focus"));
        });
        this.on("blur", function () {
            this.resize(400);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already suspected, what you did above won't work. The ckeditorGet method returns an instance of an editor, not the DOM element of the editor.

You can use the [focus event](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#event%3afocus) of ckeditor to determine what to do when the editor receives focus.

Example:

```
$("#Content").ckeditorGet().on('focus', function(e) {
    // do what you want on focus
});
```

May I suggest enabling the [autogrow plugin](http://nightly.ckeditor.com/7397/_samples/autogrow.html) to change the content area size? It's more generalized to the size of your content, and may work better than trying to resize on your own.

Comment: Thanks - I worked it out last night (and implemented it slightly differently due to my needs), I'm just about to update the question with the answer :)

Comment: Oh, and thanks for the autoGrow suggestion - actually enhances the experience (I only wanted to increase width when focused, so the autogrow plugin is perfect).